# Spelling the Number of a Decimal using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to covert a decimal number into words. I used the function from [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650):

```
FUNCTION spell_number( p_number in number ) return varchar2
as
    type myArray is table of varchar2(255);

    l_str myArray := myArray( '',
    ' thousand ', ' million ',
    ' billion ', ' trillion ',
    ' quadrillion ', ' quintillion ',
     ' sextillion ', ' septillion ',
     ' octillion ', ' nonillion ',
     ' decillion ', ' undecillion ',
     ' duodecillion ' );

    l_num varchar2(50) default trunc( p_number );
    l_return varchar2(4000);

begin

    for i in 1 .. l_str.count
    loop
    exit when l_num is null;

    if ( substr(l_num, length(l_num)-2, 3) <> 0 ) then

        l_return := to_char(to_date(substr(l_num, length(l_num)-2, 3),'J' ),'Jsp' ) || l_str(i) || l_return;

    end if;

    l_num := substr( l_num, 1, length(l_num)-3 );

    end loop;

    return l_return;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        return null;
        IF ( FND_LOG.LEVEL_STATEMENT >= ZX_LOG.G_CURRENT_RUNTIME_LEVEL ) THEN
            ZX_LOG.STRING(FND_LOG.LEVEL_STATEMENT, 'ZX.TRL.ZX_WTRL_JL_EXTRACT_PKG.SPELL_NUMBER',
                SUBSTR('Exception Occured in SPELL_NUMBER: '||sqlerrm, 1, 3000));
        END IF;
        FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG, SUBSTR('Exception Occured in SPELL_NUMBER: '||sqlerrm, 1, 3000));
end SPELL_NUMBER;
```

but when i use it for decimals with two digits (i.e. 80), it shows only a single digit (Eight), see below:

```
select jaaw.tax_amt
    ,   case when abs(jaaw.tax_amt) <> 0 then zx_wtrl_jl_extract_pkg.spell_number (abs(jaaw.tax_amt)) else null end whole_num
        ,    case when INSTR(abs(jaaw.tax_amt),'.') > 0 then
                case when SUBSTR(abs(jaaw.tax_amt), INSTR(abs(jaaw.tax_amt),'.')+1) <> 0 then
                    spell_number (SUBSTR(abs(jaaw.tax_amt), INSTR(abs(jaaw.tax_amt),'.')+1))
                else
                    null
                end
            else
                null
            end DCIMAL
    ,   regexp_substr(jaaw.tax_amt, '\d+$') decimal_new
from    (select 58.80 tax_amt from dual
        union all
        select 31.36 from dual
        union all
        select 117.6 from dual) jaaw;
```

The results are below:

```
TAX_AMT WHOLE_NUM               DCIMAL      DCIMAL_NEW
------  ---------------------   --------    -----------
58.8    Fifty-Eight             Eight       8
117.6   One Hundred Seventeen   Six         6
31.36   Thirty-One              Thirty-Six  36
```

I'm not sure why I'm not getting Eighty for the Decimals.

Comment: Numbers don't have trailing (or leading) zeros. You can see that in the first column of your results. 'Eight' is correct really. (I'd argue that 'Thirty-six' in the last result isn't really correct; it's thirty-six hundredths maybe, but I'd say the whole number as 'thirty one point three six', not 'thirty one point thirty six'. [Also see here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/55000); though this might be cultural?)

Comment: You just can replace the second usage of `spell_number()` function with `spell_number(RPAD(SUBSTR(ABS(jaaw.tax_amt), INSTR(ABS(jaaw.tax_amt), '.') + 1),2,'0'))` in order to get the value for `DCIMAL` column as desired.

Comment: @AlexPoole i should've clarified that this is for Currency Amounts. so 191.8 should really be one hundred ninety one dollars and eighty cents

Comment: OK, so in the second row the .6 should be treated as 60? Then Barbaros' suggestion should do what you want (as long as you don't have any initial values with *more then* two decimal places.).

Answer (score 1):

First, you can simplify the function a lot, leveraging the Julian date format elements (as shown below).

Second, to separate the integer part from the decimal part, use arithmetic functions, not string functions. The integer part is trivial (use `trunc`); for the decimal part multiply the tax amount by 100 and take the remainder modulo 100. (Of course, you can use this also with the AskTom function, or any other function to spell out integers).

Function:

```
create or replace function spell_number (p_number number) return varchar2 as
begin
  return case p_number when 0 then 'zero' 
                       else to_char(to_date(p_number, 'j'), 'jsp') end;
end;
/
```

(note that 0 requires explicit handling, since the first date in Julian notation is 1).

Query (using more data for testing):

```
with
  sample_data (tax_amt) as (
    select    58.8  from dual union all
    select   117.6  from dual union all
    select    31.36 from dual union all
    select 74263    from dual union all
    select     0.1  from dual union all
    select     0    from dual union all
    select  1000.02 from dual
  )
select tax_amt,
       spell_number(trunc(tax_amt))          as whole_num,
       spell_number(mod(100 * tax_amt, 100)) as dcimal
from   sample_data
;
   TAX_AMT WHOLE_NUM                                            DCIMAL      
---------- ---------------------------------------------------- ------------
      58.8 fifty-eight                                          eighty      
     117.6 one hundred seventeen                                sixty       
     31.36 thirty-one                                           thirty-six  
     74263 seventy-four thousand two hundred sixty-three        zero        
        .1 zero                                                 ten         
         0 zero                                                 zero        
   1000.02 one thousand                                         two
```